# Get Webform submission count using custom module

Tags: 7, webforms

I would like to get the submission count of a user using custom code in my module. Which variable stores this?

I tried to do dsm on $node and there was an array for webform inside the $node object but in that array I couldn't find the submission count for the current user. But then, $node shouldn't contain that value, of course. So how do I get this value?

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I figured it out.

There is a function [webform_get_submission_count](http://api.drupal.psu.edu/api/drupal/modules!contrib!webform!includes!webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_get_submission_count/nittany7) in the webmodule includes file that does. Just added these lines and got it my count. Sweet and simple.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
$mysubmission_count = webform_get_submission_count($node->nid, $user->uid);
```

Comment: where did you put this? custom module or computed field?

Comment: @Michael: I did this in a custom module.

Comment: ok thanks. When you enabled that custom module, how did you make it show on certain content types that need to print webform submissions?

Comment: @Michael: This can be done by checking the node type which is stored in `$node->type`. Read the docs regarding this or google it.